# AppSync - creating nested mutation with array and objects?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

Does AppSync support nested single mutation?

I want to call a single mutation which will insert records into two tables, eg: `User` and `Roles` tables in DynamoDB.

Something like this for example:

```
createUser(
   input: {
      Name: "John"
      Email: "user@domain.com"
      LinesRoles: [
        { Name: "Role 1" }
        { Name: "Role 2" }
      ]
   }) {
        Id
        Name
        LinesRoles {
          Id
          Name
        }
      }
```

Do I need to create two resolvers in AppSync for `User` and `Roles` to insert the records in both tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of three ways to achieve this:

1. Use a [BatchPutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb-batch-put-item) to save records into two tables at once. However, you won’t be able to use any `ConditionExpression`
2. Use a [pipeline resolver](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/pipeline-resolvers.html) with two AppSync functions where one function makes a PutItem to the `Roles` table and the other to the `User` table. However, you need to be ok with potentially inconsistent scenarios where the record has been inserted in one table but not in the other.
3. Use a [Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-lambda.html) resolver that does the write to 2 tables inside a DynamoDB transaction.

Comment: To use BatchPutItem, how to get new inserted UserId before creating roles in the Roles Table? Do I need 1 or 2 resolvers for this case?

Comment: When you use BatchPutItem you have to specify the entire item for both tables at the same time. So in your case you need to know the userId before inserting, maybe use a UUID?